# HTML table with button that spans multiple cells clickable area

Tags: html, css

It seems that the clickable area of a button spanning multiple cells is only defined on the cell where it originates from. Would anyone know how to extend it across all cells it spans? Please see snippet for example.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom-scroll table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-nonfluid" style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2012</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2013</th> 
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2014</th>  
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2015</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2016</th> 
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2017</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2018</th>
    <tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
      <td style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-block" style="width:200px">edit</button></td>    
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
    <tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot tr element

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I have added the tr element. Issue still remains with button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `position:relative;` + `z-index:1;` to bring it at front.

But i believe **the best woud be to span the cell where it is being hold** to keep the full meaning of your table if read by a screenreader or any kind of engines.*(remove styles and it is obvious edit button stands in a single cell)*

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom-scroll table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-nonfluid" style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2012</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2013</th> 
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2014</th>  
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2015</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2016</th> 
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2017</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2018</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
      <td style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-block" style="width:200px;position:relative;z-index:1;">edit</button></td>    
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
</div>
```

**NOTE** that 200px will span a few cells on a small screen , but only one on big screen :( *(hit full page to see snippet in action )*

Comment: I didn't want to make the question too complicated, but, I am using .on('resize', function(){ $('.button_id').css('width', $('.button_id').parent().width()*w);}); to adjust for different screens.

Comment: @spitz okay, then a `width:XX%` or `XXvw` might do if cells number are always the same and spread evenly ;)

Answer (score 1):

use   `colspan` in `td` :  `<td colspan="3">`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom-scroll table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-nonfluid" style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed;">
  <thead>
    <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2012</th>
    <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2013</th> 
    <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2014</th>  
    <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2015</th>
    <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2016</th> 
    <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2017</th>
    <th style="vertical-align:middle;">2018</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
    <td colspan="3"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-block">edit</button></td>    
    <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
    <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
    <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: relative;"></td>
  </tbody>  
</table>
</div>
```